# Import PST in Evolution 3.2.1

Tags: 11.10, evolution, ms-exchange

How can I import a PST from Windows 2007 into Ubuntu 11.10's Evolution 3.2.1?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[readpst](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/readpst.1.html): This software will allow you to convert all your .pst MS Outlook files into .mbox files. These .mbox files can then be imported into Evolution using its Import feature.

To install the readpst program in 11.10:

```
sudo apt-get install readpst
```

Sample command (assuming that you have a dual-core processor, you can run this task in parallel using the -j switch):

```
mkdir ~/Evolution

readpst -D -j 2 -o ~/Evolution -q -r ~/outlook.pst
```

You will need to change the paths to where you want to save the files and where you have saved your original .pst file.

After this, start Evolution and use the import feature to import these .mbox files, one-by-one.

Comment: In newer versions of Ubuntu, install `readpst` thanks to the following command: `sudo apt install pst-utils`.

Answer (score 0):

While @rigved has the correct answer, I'm writing this for those who may not use Ubuntu and need a bit of extra help. I use Gentoo, so this is how I installed `readpst`:

1. Install `gnome-extra/libgsf` (a gnome dependency, I use KDE)
2. Download libpst from https://www.five-ten-sg.com/libpst/packages/. I used `libpst-0.6.75`
3. `./configure`, `sudo make` and `sudo make install`